# Some view counts in main page not coloured?

Tags: bug, design

Is there any reason for having one view count coloured and not the other (with higher view count)?

[image]

[image]

Checked on Chrome 40.0.2214.115 (64-bit).

Comment: Ha, the word "views" is colored correctly... I imagine there's another style overriding the fix they pushed a few weeks ago.

Comment: The view count determines the overall brightness. On my iPad (which uses Safari), the number and text are in the same color. What browser is this?

Comment: .. Hmm. In the home page view, this `div` is split in two parts (but they still ought to have the same class), but when selecting a Favourite tag, it appears in a single `div`. (Also the trinity 'votes' , 'answers' , 'views' are not left to right, but stacked vertically. A minor design difference?)

Comment: Cannot reproduce (anymore?) in Chrome 40.0.2214.115 on Windows.